# How can I transform QTabWidget coordinates to its child's coordinates?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14

I'm trying to generate a right-click menu on a QTabWidget (lists) containing only QListWidgets. I get a menu below where I click the distance of the tab bar's height, which is expected because the context menu is applied to the QTabWidget.

```
void onCustomContextMenuRequested(const QPoint& pos) {
    QListWidgetItem * item = ((QListWidget*)(lists->currentWidget()))->itemAt(pos);
    if (item) showContextMenu(item, QListWidget(lists->currentWidget()).viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
void showContextMenu(QListWidgetItem* item, const QPoint& globalPos) {
    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction(item->text());
    menu.exec(globalPos);
}
```

I can get the menu to appear at the mouse, while still referring to an item about 100px beneath it, by changing

```
QListWidget(lists->currentWidget()).viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
```

to

```
QListWidget(lists->currentWidget()).viewport()->mapToParent(mapToGlobal(pos)));
```

But I can't get the menu to refer to the item I am clicking on. I have tried transforming to and from parent coordinates to no effect.

```
QPoint pos_temp = ((QListWidget*)(lists->currentWidget()))->viewport()->mapFromParent(pos);
if (item) showContextMenu(item, QListWidget(lists->currentWidget()).viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos_temp));
```

I have also tried to and from global coordinate, and combinations of global and parent, to undesirable effect.

So how can I get the right click menu to refer to the item I am clicking on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position sent by the `customContextMenuRequested` signal is with respect to the widget where the connection is established, and in this case I am assuming that it is the main widget so when using `itemAt()` of `QListWidget` it throws inadequate values since this method waits for the position with respect to the `viewport()`. The approach in these cases is to convert that local position to a global one and then map that global to a local position of the final widget.

In the next part I show an example.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMenu>

class Widget: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTabWidget *lists;
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QWidget(parent){
        lists = new QTabWidget;
        setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
        connect(this, &Widget::customContextMenuRequested, this, &Widget::onCustomContextMenuRequested);
        auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(lists);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            auto list = new QListWidget;
            lists->addTab(list, QString("tab-%1").arg(i));
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                list->addItem(QString("item %1-%2").arg(i).arg(j));
            }
        }

    }
private slots:
    void onCustomContextMenuRequested(const QPoint& pos){
        QPoint globalPos = mapToGlobal(pos);
        QListWidget *list = static_cast<QListWidget *>(lists->currentWidget());
        if(list){
            QPoint p = list->viewport()->mapFromGlobal(globalPos);
            QListWidgetItem *item = list->itemAt(p);
            if(item)
                showContextMenu(item, globalPos);
        }
    }

    void showContextMenu(QListWidgetItem* item, const QPoint& globalPos) {
        QMenu menu;
        menu.addAction(item->text());
        menu.exec(globalPos);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49332159) is the complete example.

Comment: This worked when the only widget in the tab was a list. If I add a button above the list, then the right click menu appears about the distance of a button above the mouse, where it would have if there were no button. The menu refers to the item that it is hovering over, not where I clicked. In addition, adding `int tab_index = lists->tabBar()->tabAt(pos);
        if (tab_index!=-1) showListContextMenu(tab_index, globalPos);` works until I add the button, then will produce a similarly displaced menu when I right click on a tab, but the menu will refer to where I clicked.